# swig compiled binary Python Azure import error

Tags: python, azure, import, importerror, swig

I'm trying to run an azure function app. I've created the file structure, functions, etc. as needed for my code to run. When I run locally, everything works just fine. However, when I deploy to the Azure function app and try to run on the server, I get an import error:  `ImportError: cannot import name '_<swig_compiled_binary>' from 'other_functions_path'`

I can't understand why this would be the case. For those wondering, the package structure is as follows:

```
HttpTriggerIntro
  __init__.py
  function.json
other_functions_path
  __init__.py
  other_functions.py
  _<swig_compiled_binary>.pyd
```

I don't have any external library imports beyond the swig compiled binary file, everything else is standard python 3.7 library calls, and as I said, everything works locally in the virtual environment.

If more info is needed I can provide it.

Edit:
removed portion where I talked about circular import, this is not the cause.

Comment: No, I don't think I actually have a circular import, I think that was just some weird artifact, as when I move the other_functions.py out to other_functions_path I don't get that circular import error, but rather just the generic one seen above in the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Azure functions use a linux operating system for python runtime stacks. If you use a .pyd, that is compiled on windows, and the azure runtime stack will not recognize it. You have to use a .so compiled on linux for this to work.